# SqlDataReader["Attribute"].ToString doesn't work

Tags: c#

Actually, i have this part of code to compare if the password enter by the user is the same as the one in the SQL Server Database :

```
if (drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"].ToString() == strMotDePasse)
```

I don't understand why `drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"].ToString()` doesn't work.

Do you have any solutions, please ?

First Actualisation :

Here's my full code where the part of code above is in :

```
private bool Authentifier(string strNomUtilisateur, string strMotDePasse)
{
    bool bOk = false;
    // Cryptage du mot de passe
    strMotDePasse = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(strMotDePasse, "MD5");
    // Création d'une connexion SGBD
    SqlConnection oConnexion = new SqlConnection(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SaisieHeuresConnectionString"]));
    // Définition de la requête à exécuter
    SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Utilisateurs WHERE NomUtilisateur='" + strNomUtilisateur + "'", oConnexion);
    try
    {
        // Ouverture de la connexion et exécution de la requête
        oConnexion.Open();
        SqlDataReader drUtilisateur = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
        // Parcours de la liste des utilisateurs
        while (drUtilisateur.Read())
        {
            if (drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"].ToString().Equals(strMotDePasse))
            {
                bOk = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        bOk = false;
    }
    oConnexion.Close();
    return bOk;
}
```

I hash my passwords into MD5 (because it's the hashing method that is asking to me).

Comment: What does this mean: 'doesn't work'?

Comment: I hope you're not storing plain text passwords - That would be very bad practice.

Comment: Please post the whole code that leads to this line. In particular how do you create the query and how do you read the data resulting from the query

Comment: Did you execute `drUtilisateur.Read()` before actually reading out the value?

Comment: Encrypt password and then store in DB. while comparing encrypt the user password with same key and then compare with password stored in DB

Comment: MD5 is not encryption but hashing. And it is not secure.

Comment: I wouldn't use a catch in that way. If there is an error you will never see it. Just a false returned like the password is invalid. Better add a _catch(Exception ex)_ and then show the ex.Message value to understand the reasons of the (possible) failure. For example, if the variable _strNomUtilisateur_ contains a single quote your code will fail with a syntax error. Start using parameters ASAP

Comment: As mentioned, don't store passwords/MD5 hashes like that in a database. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords.

Comment: + other problems with this code is that you don't use sql parameters (sql injection risk) + don't swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

In reality, my program works.

The anomaly was that when a user enter his password, the progral hash it to MD5  ; letters are in uppercase whereas i enter it in lowercase in my database.

So, when you compare two password in MD5 in a code, take care of the case.

Comment: Next to this, I assume that you also know that MD5 is not secure?

Comment: I see it but my superior ask me to use it ; i've got no choice but to obey to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"] != DBNull.Value) {
    drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"].ToString().equals(strMotDePasse)
} else {
    //null
}
```

**Note**: Please don't store passwords in plain text...

Comment: And what if drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"] is null?

Comment: I try it ; unfortunately the same result :(

Comment: But WHAT result?? What happens?

Comment: It doesn't enter in the if loop ; the "strMotDePasse" contains my password, but the drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"].ToString still have nothing.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at your `while` loop to debug and see if that value exists...

Comment: `drUtilisateur.GetString("MotDePasse")` should work, but as far as I can remember this is the same as ToString().

Comment: `GetString()` accepts an integer value, so no. It only works if you know the indexes of your columns.